# Two concerns with the terms "twee" and "dandy"

Tags: word-meaning

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.
>
> Much of what Maccari put on the runway might actually have been better appreciated in a more intimate setting where audience members are able to put their hands on the fabric, see the details up close. But putting Perry Ellis on the runway during the inaugural season of New York Fashion Week: Men’s, served a larger purpose. It sent a message: This, too, is fashion. And there’s nothing to fear.
>
> Perry Ellis lends a helping hand by showing a guy just how to wear one of those sheer shirts that designers are putting on the runway, with a man’s pecs on full display. He should wear it with the easy élan of a T-shirt: casually, understated. With shorts.
>
> Men’s fashion has moved out of the realm of the obscure, **the twee or dandy** . It is the segment of the fashion business that has been steadily ticking upwards in sales. And this week has underscored the reality that there are a host of young menswear brands that have a strong point of view, a wellspring of creative energy and a desire to build real businesses, not just vanity ones.

I know the neaning of the word **twee** & **dandy** , twee means interestingly and differently perfectvand nice pice of art or design for instance. And **dandy** means just good. But I have two concerns here:

1. How does being twee or dandy refer to moving out of realm of obscure? What is the use of twee and dandy here?
2. Exactly in the nexf srntence, the writer has used the word **it** . What is the segment of the fashion business ? Which segment is being reffered to here?

Comment: That is an obscure phrase for me and the context doesn't help.  I'll leave it to others to help on this one as that phrase comes off as noise to me.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase **dandy** here does not mean **good**. The noun definition of "dandy" is "a man unduly devoted to style, neatness, and fashion in dress and appearance." The adjective implied here refers to the sort of clothing worn by a dandy, not "dandy" in the sense of "fine and dandy." **Twee** does not mean "interestingly and differently perfect." It means "excessively or affectedly quaint, pretty, or sentimental." It is also listed as a derogatory term. So the phrase refers to fashion being viewed as being silly and inappropriate for men. That is really all that is going on here: the dandy's focus on clothing is no more excessive than that of the standard model or socialite.

As for the second sentence, **it** simply refers to the men's fashion business, viewed as a subset of fashion in general.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that "dandy" is an old word that has deep meaning in British and French cultures. It may have a negative connotation by some modern definitions, but I think in the fashion world many people have been and still are proud of being "dandy."